# Copy task zeros out pre-existing files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following task:

```
task copyToLibs(type: Copy) {
    into "libs"
    from configurations.compile
}
```

My libs directory already contains a few unique (not part of my gradle dependencies) libraries.  When I run the gradle task, gradle copies all of my dependencies to the libs directory as hoped for.  The problem is that after the copy, each of my pre-existing jar files now have zero bytes.  They were fine before running the task.  I checked, the files are not located under ~/.gradle.   Why would running that task zero out my pre-existing jar files?

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Comment: What version of Gradle? Which OS are you using?

Comment: Gradle 4.7.  64 bit LinuxMint.

Comment: I just upgraded to Gradle 4.9.  Same problem.